# using java streams to rank data in an array list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` containing strings for example list 1 may be a list of names:

`Bill, Bill, Bill, Henry, Sue, Sue`

**How do I use java streams to return the array as follows in ranked order (by occurrence)?**

`Bill, Bill, Bill, Sue, Sue, Henry`

It would also be great to know how to display the final ranking of 
`Bill`, `Sue`, `Henry`. I have the following code:

```
System.out.println(
   name.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a->a))
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

where name is the array.
It works fine and arranges the array according to name but I also want to introduce ranking.

Comment: Why use streams? Just `name.sort();` will do it. Then print the list. (btw, an ArrayList is not an array, it’s a List)

Comment: `names.sort(Comparator.comparing(names.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()))::get).reversed());`

Comment: thanks @shmosel that was just what I was looking for. Is good to see how it is done really helps me learn.

Comment: @shmosel can you add that as an answer? At first I thought it was very heavy on performance to stream the list again and again. Thought it would be better to group first, then stream the resulting map and flatMap into a list. But your use of the method reference prevents the re-streaming, and all in one statement... nice!

Comment: @MalteHartwig indeed nice, but assumes two things: 1) `names` *can* be sorted in place 2) does not return an array; otherwise I love it!

Comment: @Eugene there is no requirement for returning an array. Tho OP inconsistently says “I have an ArrayList” at the beginning but “where name is the array” at the end, however since the OP used “`name.stream()`” in the code example, it seems to be an `ArrayList`, not an array, thus allows sorting in-place. like in shmosel’s comment.

Comment: @Holger what if `name` is a unmodifiable ?

Comment: @marsouf the simplest solution is `list = new ArrayList<>(list)` and you have a mutable, efficiently sortable list. Or you consider a Stream operation in that case, but it may still be more complicated.

Comment: @shmosel I think your code in comments is very, very inefficient. no idea how it has received a few upvotes. it's totally nonsense. the code provided by your answer is much better.

Comment: @user_3380739 I think you have a very, very poor understanding of how it works.

Comment: @ shmosel ok, I'm. I misunderstood it. I thought `::get` is `.get`.

Answer (score 1):

First it's a little bit unclear what you actually want to achieve: a `List<List<String>>` or `List<String[]>` or a `String[]`...

One one hand you want `Bill, Bill, Bill, Sue, Sue, Henry`, but if your list is `{Bill, Bill, Bill, Sue, Henry, Henry}; {Bill, Gene, Sue}` what would your result be in such case? A single `String[]` or .... what exactly? You also mention that *how to display the final ranking of  Bill, Sue, Henry*, which obviously means something else entirely...

In any case:

Shmosel solution in comments is indeed very nice! (but assume two things, that your list is editable, thus you can sort it and that you want a sorted List as opposed to an array). And you can't refactor that to a single stream operation that returns an array, because that would mean consuming the stream twice... which you can't.

You can do it via two operations:

```
List<String> flat = all.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    String[] result = flat.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> Collections.frequency(flat, x)).reversed())
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

This will for the input that I gave above will be:

```
[Bill, Bill, Bill, Bill, Henry, Henry, Sue, Sue, Gene]
```

If you want to sort each list, then you could use:

```
 List<List<String>> res = all.stream()
            .map(x -> x.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(y -> Collections.frequency(x, y)).reversed())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the result will be:

```
 [[Bill, Bill, Bill, Henry, Henry, Sue], [Bill, Gene, Sue]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer on my own, i will just refactor [shmosel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549590/using-java-streams-to-rank-data-in-an-array-list#comment90067988_51549590) to take into account [Eugene's remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549590/using-java-streams-to-rank-data-in-an-array-list#comment90074702_51549590).

```
final List<String> names = <your names here>;

final Map<String, Long> namesByOccurence = names.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        Collectors.counting()
    ));

final Comparator<String> byOccurrence = Comparator.comparing(namesByOccurence::get);

final String[] res = names.stream()
    .sorted(byOccurrence.reversed())
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as the comparator does not need to iterate the list again and again to check the frequency. Still, thumbs up to [Eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553975/7653073) for the explanation about converting between list and array.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to group them, sort groups by size, then flat map:

```
names.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size).reversed())
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you could include ranking :

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Henry", "Sue", "Sue");

    Map<String, Long> m = l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(m);
```

the result is : 
{Sue=2, Bill=3, Henry=1}